# How to create a view that lists all taxonomy terms of a vocabulary, filtered by a term id?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, 9

I have a lot of different vocabularies. On The taxonomy page (the standard view provided) I would like to add a block (view) that takes the current taxonomy id from the url/page and displays all taxonomy terms belonging to the same vocabulary.
I tried adding a contextual filter, but when I choose term id from url, the view only shows one term, but I would like to show all terms of the vocabulary the term belongs to.

Of course I could create a block for each vocabulary, but as I have a lot, I'm searching for a more dynamic approach.

For Example: on the page /taxonomy/term/39
I would like to add a block (view) that takes the taxonomy id 39 and lists all terms of the vocabulary the id 39 belongs to.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You should provide more context for this question, e.g. your views configuration, so that users here can better understand your problem.

Comment: From the top of my head, I'd say you also need a relationship to the parent vocabulary in order to pull in other terms. But it's a bit difficult to say without seeing your views configuration.

Comment: I tried to clarify and edited my question

Comment: I just played a bit around with views and it seems to me that you can't do what you want with Drupal core. There is no option to add a relationship from a term to a vocabulary and no option either to retrieve the vocabulary from the current term page. So either there is a contrib module that solves this that I couldn't find, or you need to do some custom coding to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I created a views argument_default plugin that did the trick:

```
public function getArgument() {
  if (($taxonomy_term = $this->routeMatch->getParameter('taxonomy_term')) && $taxonomy_term instanceof TermInterface) {
    $vocabulary = $taxonomy_term->bundle();
    return $vocabulary;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Glad you found a solution.